# Use IF and VLOOKUP to change a cell value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to use Vlookup in VBA to change a value elsewhere in the sheet, based on the selection from a drop-down list.

I also want to combine this with an IF statement, so I want to select a calculated output number, if the valued looked up above is changed to 50%.

code is:

```
Dim nmcr_apalutamide_progress_num As Integer

Dim nmcr_apalutamide_ptc As Double

Range("nmcr_apalutamide_ptc").Value = 0.5

Dim result As Integer
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("model")


If Range("nmcr_apalutamide_ptc").Value = 0.5 Then
Range("result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet.Range("nmcr_comparator_treatment"), sheet.Range("E52:H61"), 4, False)").Value = 0.5
'also change comparator percentage to 50%'


result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet.Range("nmcr_comparator_treatment"), sheet.Range("D139:H146"), 5, False)
'find outcome comparator number'

End If
```

This shouldn't be that hard to do, I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: If you want to change a value that you found with `Vlookup` then instead of `Vlookup` (which gives you a value and not a cell reference) you need to use `Match` to get the row number of your find and then use `Cells(MatchedRow, Column).Value = 0.5` to change the found value.

Comment: why are you setting `Range("nmcr_apalutamide_ptc").Value = 0.5
` and then checking `If Range("nmcr_apalutamide_ptc").Value = 0.5 Then`?

Comment: Again default value is not 0.5, there are other options. In this condition however I want to set nmcr_apalutamide_ptc to 0.5 and compare it with one other, also at 0.5.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I am not quite sure how this code should go as the row will change depending on which option I select from the list?

Comment: Please include some example data (for example as a screenshot) and give a good explanation of what you want to lookup and check. Your code does not make any senes at all (sorry to have to say that) and I see no logic in it. I think you are somehow up the wrong tree.

Comment: I cannot add attachments. It has worked for the first condition, but when I want to select the comparative treatment from the drop it does not work. I want to select one option from a dropdown. Based on this selection, I would like to change the proportion of the selected option (which is mentioned  elsewhere in the sheet.) This proportion is then utilised to calculate an output value, I hope this is clearer

Comment: I doubt that this code has worked. This must immediately throw an exeption. • And I doubt that this will become more clear without a screenshot. Note that you cannot upload files but you should be able to insert a screenshot using the toolbar buttons in the editor here. Just [edit] your original quesiton.